# Formulas in work calculations changing to "Automatic" though i choose them to "Manual"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013 and eachtime I change the formula calculations into "Manual" and save the file but when I open the excel, it is changing to "Automatic" by default. My file size is huge and I normally keep them to "Manual". 
When I close all my Excel files and open a new book, then it goes back to "Automatic". Can someone help me on this.

Thank you, Firoz

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106544/how-to-set-calculation-mode-to-manual-when-opening-an-excel-file

Answer (score 0):

Check the path C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART and see if you have anything in there.  If you do, move it to a temp folder of some sort in your document library.  If that resolves your issue, you can safely delete the moved file.  If you are trying to change the default behavior of Excel to always be manual calculation, then you will have to save a workbook with that setting to this path.  You will have to put up with always having an extra workbook to close when exiting Excel, but I know of no other way of accomplishing this.